# zsh: permission denied while trying to use 'radb' on Mac OS

Tags: python, pip

I have python 3 installed and the version is 3.7.

Then I follow the RA documentation to install the radb from my terminal.

I put comment: `pip3 install radb` and it installed successfully.

Then I download the beers.ra example from the page.

Then I tried the comment `radb -i beers.ra beers.db` and it return `zsh: command not found: radb`.

Then I tried comment "pip3 show -f radb" and found out the path way so I try again by typing:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/radb radb -i beers.ra beers.db`

and it return

```
zsh: permission denied: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/radb
```

Then I search Google and try to gain the permission by use:

`sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/radb radb -i beers.ra beers.db`

but it return

```
chown: radb: No such file or directory
chown: -i: No such file or directory
chown: beers.ra: No such file or directory
chown: beers.db: No such file or directory
```

How do I gain the permission and fixed this issue?

On the documentation is says if I type `radb -i beers.ra beers.db` and it will create a simple database for me. But my radb comment doesn't even working.

Comment: `pip3 show -f radb | grep /bin/`

Comment: @phd After using this comment I got "../../../bin/radb" then I use "../../../bin/radb radb -i beers.ra beers.db" and I got "zsh: no such file or directory: ../../../bin/radb"

Comment: `../../../` is relative to `site-packages` so the full path should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bin/radb` or  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/radb`.

Comment: @phd It works!! Thank you

Comment: @phd But if I run "../../bin/radb radb -i beers.ra beers.db" it return "radb: error: unrecognized arguments: beers.db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` puts the scripts into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bin/` so add it to `$PATH`:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Do I just run this comment in terminal? Cause when I press return I shows nothing.

Comment: I got something, when I run "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/radb -i beers.ra beers.db" it says "No such file or directory: 'beers.ra'". But I already put the file in the radb file inside. How can I sloved it?

Comment: *No such file or directory: 'beers.ra'"* Wrong directory? `cd` to the right dir or use full paths.

Comment: I solved it out by your hints and not it it can simple run by "radb" command in terminal. Many thanks for you help!